# Geth couldn't run in background with nohup or child process

Tags: go-ethereum

I was trying to let `geth` run in background so I don't have to keep my terminal session alive or get rid of annoying block sync log by using 
`nohup`:

```
nohup geth --testnet &
```

However `geth` seemed to hang even though the process existed when I checked with:

```
ps aux | grep geth
```

and I couldn't attach another geth session because:

```
geth attach ipc:/Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

failed.

Am I doing anything wrong or it's just that `geth` is not supposed to run in background which is completely nonsense to me.

**Edit 1:**

I did try to watch the log to see if the server can do anything:

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

Nothing was there that's why I thought `geth` seemed to hang.

Comment: Can you run as: `geth --testnet` ?

Comment: Sure I can run `geth --testnet` successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you can run `geth --testnet` successfull, there should be no problem with `geth`. Please be sure to use latest version of `geth`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install git
$ git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
$ sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libgmp3-dev golang
$ cd go-ethereum/
$ param update
$ git pull
$ make geth
```

Based on your comment:

> geth is not supposed to run in background

You may have to run `geth` as being sudo, my `geth.ipc` file required root access.

```
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial unix /Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc: 
connect: permission denied
```

I had overcome this issue as follows:

First create a "server.sh" file:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup geth --testnet &
echo 'loadScript("pass.js")' | sudo geth ipc:/Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc console #You are not required to add this line.
echo 'net'                   | sudo geth ipc:/Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc console #You are not required to add this line.
```

//If you have an additional script you can load and/or check `net` status after `geth` starts running.

Than create "client.sh" file: I assume your datadir is at `/.ethereum`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo geth ipc:/Users/myname/Library/Ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc console
```

Run following command: //This will run geth on the background with the help of nohup.

```
$ sudo bash server.sh
```

At final step when you run this command, you will be attached:

```
$ bash client.sh
```

You can observe the log file on "nohup.out" file.

```
$ sudo cat nohup.out
```

Comment: Your suggestion of running it under `sudo` works for me, now I can have `nohup` successful detached `geth` process. However, I still don't understand why exactly do we need to run it under `sudo`. What's the difference between `nohup` and an attached process that deal with permission? Avoiding `sudo` when don't really need to is recommended isn't it?

Comment: There is no difference, you just have to run `geth` with `sudo`, either if you are using `nohup` or not. This problem is related to `geth.ipc`, where it requires root access.

Comment: Then I don't think you are right in my case. Since geth is running under my non-root account and it creates the `geth.ipc` thus `geth.ipc` should be accessible without root permission. Evidence is that I could successfully attach a `geth` session to the ipc while running `geth` without child process (`&` or `nohup`). There should be still something missing here.

Comment: You may try `chmod o+w geth.ipc` , The o+w command tells the system you want to give others write permission to the file. This may remove the usage of `sudo`.

Comment: Yeah I know that I can give access to others but that's not what I was asking for in the comment before. Why did `nohup` need `sudo`? It still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Well I am having the same issue, using `sudo` was the only way I get over this issue. Maybe to access the `geth` child which runs on the background `geth.ipc` always require root access? I will further investigate and update you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51039/discussion-between-vutran-and-avatar).

Answer (score 5):

Just a troubleshooting idea. As far as I know, nohup and geth should be a valid combination.

Probability is that nohup is working fine but geth isn't behaving the way you expect. Possibly geth isn't getting far enough to start/support the IPC connection. No IPC doesn't mean geth is completely dead. Consider logging the output with >> geth.log

```
$ nohup geth --testnet >> geth.log &
```

and watching with

```
$ watch geth.log
```

You can make geth more talkative than usual with --verbosity

```
$ nohup geth --testnet --verbosity 5 >> geth.log &
```

Also, be sure you're IPC connection is pointing to a valid path. There should be a geth.ipc visible in that folder. I would make sure that much works using multiple terminals, and then re-introduce nohup into the mix.

In my case (yours might differ) testnet ipc path would be:

```
~/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
```

Dot in front of "ethereum" is important. The folder is hidden, but it's there.

Comment: I have no problem with ipc path because I can run it successfully without child process. My thinking process was the same as you suggested but there's something different. You suggested to use `>>` to direct output to a file, I usually use single `>` to do so. Is there any different? I find it strange to use `>>`. Anw, please see my updated question.

Comment: >> just concatenates the log instead of overwriting it every time. Possibly someone can chime in with an insight about nohup.

Comment: If you're starting geth from an unstable remote connection and you need it to keep running, screen might be good option. For local ops, I use terminator, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Yeah, I know that there exists some other solutions. But I really want to dive into this to know exactly what's wrong because I never been failed using `nohup` before. I do think that `geth` is doing something strange to some UNIX signals relatedto child process.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Geth run as a systemd service. 
Refer to here: https://github.com/bas-vk/config/blob/master/geth-systemd-service.md

OR

You could also run the Geth Docker container and detach using the `-d` tag.

OR

Start a screen/Tmux session, run Geth then detach.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, however i want to know how nohup and child process didn't work?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.